# Prueba humana en formulario html y php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario en html y php y quiero añadir una prueba humana como un reCAPTCHA o una suma o algo similar para que no sean los robots los que manden mensajes. Me he registrado en reCAPTCHA  de google pero no no consigo ponerlo y me da el error: clave no válida.
¿Alguien sabe a que se debo o como puedo hacerlo de otra manera?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando te registras en `Google reCAPTCHA` indicándole tu dominio por ejemplo `prueba.com` te da una `key` pública y otra privada. Pues la pública la debes poner en tu formulario `HTML` de esta forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo reCAPTCHA 2.0 con PHP</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="formulario.php" method="post">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Nombre"/>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <textarea placeholder="Tu mensaje" name="message"></textarea>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc9oq8UAAAAAGrF2iQaKffb5HInhBRXcu9zOWfs"></div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando aquí:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6DC33897JN6

Comment: De acuerdo, y la clave privada donde se pone?  Muchas gracias

Comment: copio lo que has puesto, cambiando la clave, y me sigue dando este error:Error para el propietario del sitio web: el tipo de clave no es válido

Comment: En este link al final del todo viene un ejemplo de donde se debe poner la key secreta: http://jonsegador.com/2017/05/configurar-recaptcha-2-0-con-php/

Comment: Si te da ese error, es que no estas registrando bien tu dominio

Comment: de acuerdo, lo revisare, muchas gracias

Comment: Espero que te sirva, suerte !